# is minimum of convex function on different domains convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let 
$$
f(x,y)=\min(|x-c|,|y-c|),
$$
where $x,y,c \in[0,1]$. I wish to show that $f$ is quasiconvex.

I wasn't able to prove the claim for this case without tedious case analysis. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quasi-convex.

Proof:  for simplicity assume $c=0$ otherwise you can shift $f$ horizontally.

So $f(x,y)=\min (|x|,|y|)$, then each $\alpha-$level set of $f$ i.e., $$\{(x,y) \in R^2 ~ | \quad \min(|x|,|y|) \leq \alpha \}$$ is solid square, and so it is convex subset of $R^2$, therefore $f$ is quasi-convex.

Answer (score 1):

If $g_1(x)=x^2$ and $g_2(y)=(1-y)^2$, then $f(x,y)$ is not convex along the line $x=y$: $f(0,0)=f(1,1)=0$, $f(\frac12,\frac12)=\frac14$.
The same holds for your concrete example if you consider a line that passes through $x=c$ and $y=c$ at different "times".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about quasiconvexity? I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: That's right, but you could find easier counterexamples like $g_1 =x$ and $g_2 = 0$